# Access nested JSON data with Newtonsoft Linq

Tags: json, vb.net, linq, json.net

How can I access the value of `url` in the JSON string below?

JSON

```
{
    "id": "7453",
    "picture": {
        "data": {
            "is_silhouette": false,
            "url": "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p50x50\/gf6474hfff.jpg?oh=fy&oe=trtr"
        }
    }
}

Dim o As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json)
```

I can access `id` like so:

```
o("id").ToString()
```

So I would expect the following would work for the `url` property, but I get an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
o("picture.data.url").ToString()
```

Comment: `o("picture")("data")("url")` - it wont parse the string obj reference for you. its usually easier to work with when deserialized

Comment: it is also easier to see the hierarchy if you paste it into something like `jsonlint.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it one at a time.

```
Dim pic = o("picture")("data")("url")
```

I also found out that you can also do another method in Newtonsoft.Json:

```
Dim pic = o.SelectToken("picture.data.url")
```